# How to select records for the date range in sqlite

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, sqlite, date

My `date` column is of type `Text` and I am storing values in `dd/mm/yyyy` format. I want to get the records between date range form dateTimePickers. Like

```
select * from [Table] where date([date]) between 
date(dtpicker1.value.ToShortDateString().ToString()) and 
date(dtpicker2.value.ToShortDateString().ToString());
```

How to do it?

Comment: Why are you using that format? Can't you use a [supported format](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#datetime)?

Comment: I have to use that format as per the USER REQUIREMENT. Let's say I would use supported format, I will have to code for every DateTimePicker. Or I will have to change System Date Format, again that's not convenient for the USER.

Comment: And when the user's date format changes, all data in the database becomes wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it but bit tricky.

```
        string qry = "select * from [table]";
        DataTable vt = new DataTable();
        SQLiteDataAdapter da = new SQLiteDataAdapter(q, connectionString);
        da.Fill(vt);

        foreach (DataRow row in vt.Rows)
        {
            if (Convert.ToDateTime(row["DATE"].ToString()) >= Convert.ToDateTime(FromDate)
                && Convert.ToDateTime(row["DATE"].ToString()) <= Convert.ToDateTime(ToDate))
            {
                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                row.Delete();
            }
        }

        vt.AcceptChanges();
```